# Why the doors manager system is not working in editor mode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's working fine when running the game but I want to use it before running the game to know and decide what doors should be open/closed in the game.

The DoorsLockManager :
It have the ExecuteInEditMode attribute :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class DoorsLockManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public List<HoriDoorManager> Doors = new List<HoriDoorManager>();

    // The global state
    [SerializeField] private bool _globalLockState;

    // During runtime use a property instead
    public bool GlobalLockState
    {
        get { return _globalLockState; }
        set
        {
            _globalLockState = value;

            // apply it to all doors
            foreach (var door in Doors)
            {
                // now you would need it public again
                // or use the public property you had there
                door.doorLockState = _globalLockState;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        var doors = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door");
        Doors = new HoriDoorManager[doors.Length].ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < doors.Length; i++)
        {
            Doors[i] = doors[i].GetComponent<HoriDoorManager>();
        }
    }
}
```

And the editor script :

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(DoorsLockManager))]
public class DoorsLockManagerEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _doors;
    private SerializedProperty _globalLockState;

    private bool shouldOverwrite;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _doors = serializedObject.FindProperty("Doors");
        _globalLockState = serializedObject.FindProperty("_globalLockState");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        serializedObject.Update();

        shouldOverwrite = false;

        // Begin a change check here
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_globalLockState);
        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            // overwrite only once if changed
            shouldOverwrite = true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < _doors.arraySize; i++)
        {
            var door = _doors.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);

            // if door == null the script itself has an error since it can't even find the SerializedProperty
            if (door == null)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("There was an error in the editor script!\nPlease check the log", MessageType.Error);
                Debug.LogError("Couldn't get door property", target);
                return;
            }

            if (door.objectReferenceValue == null) continue;

            var serializedDoor = new SerializedObject(door.objectReferenceValue);

            var lockState = serializedDoor.FindProperty("doorLockState");

            serializedDoor.Update();

            if (lockState == null)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("There was an error in the editor script!\nPlease check the log", MessageType.Error);
                Debug.LogError("Couldn't get lockState property", target);
                return;
            }

            // HERE OVERWRITE
            if (shouldOverwrite)
            {
                lockState.boolValue = _globalLockState.boolValue;
            }
            else
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(lockState, new GUIContent("Door " + i + " Lockstate"));
            }

            serializedDoor.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Tried also to add the ExecuteInEditMode attribute to the editor script but it's still not working in the edit mode.

And the script that is attached to each door :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

public class HoriDoorManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<DoorHori> doors = new List<DoorHori>();
    public bool doorLockState;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (transform.parent != null)
        {
            Transform parent = transform.parent;
            var children = parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

            if (children != null)
            {
                foreach (Transform door in children)
                {
                    if (door.name == "Door_Left" || door.name == "Door_Right")
                        doors.Add(door.GetComponent<DoorHori>());
                }
            }
            ColorDoors(Color.red, Color.green, doorLockState);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        if (doorLockState == false)
        {
            if (doors != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < doors.Count; i++)
                {
                    doors[i].OpenDoor();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        ColorDoors(Color.red, Color.green, doorLockState);
    }

    private void ColorDoors(Color red, Color green, bool state)
    {
        List<Transform> children = new List<Transform>();

        for (int i = 0; i < doors.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (Transform child in doors[i].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
            {
                if (child == doors[i].transform)
                    continue;

                var renderer = child.GetComponent<Renderer>();
                renderer.material.shader = Shader.Find("Unlit/ShieldFX");

                if (state == true)
                {
                    renderer.material.SetColor("_MainColor", red);
                    LockState(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    renderer.material.SetColor("_MainColor", green);
                    LockState(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public bool GetLockState
    {
        get { return doorLockState; }
        set { doorLockState = value; }
    }

    private void LockState(bool state)
    {
        var collider = gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();

        if (state == false)
        {
            collider.size = new Vector3(2.3f, 2.736307f, 2.5f);
            collider.center = new Vector3(0, 1.378154f, 0);
            collider.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-1.57f, 0, -2.98f);
            collider.isTrigger = true;
        }
        else
        {
            collider.size = new Vector3(2.3f, 2.736307f, 3);
            collider.center = new Vector3(0, 1.378154f, 0);
            collider.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-1.57f, 0, -2.98f);
            collider.isTrigger = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Door lock manager system]

Comment: I found how to do it. All I had to do is to add this attribute to the HoriDoorManager script : [ExecuteAlways]  and removed the [ExecuteInEditMode] attribute from the DoorsLockManager. Working perfect.